# How to model typed @sets or @lists in JSON-LD

Tags: json-ld

Using schema.org's definition of a `Person` I can create the following schema:

```
{
    "@context": "http://www.schema.org/",
    "@type": "Person",
    "@id": "#AndyWarhol",
    "givenName": "Andy",
    "familyName": "Warhol",
    "birthDate": "1928-08-06",
    "deathDate": "1987-02-22",
    "knows": [
        {
            "@type": "Person",
            "@id": "#JeanMichelBasquiat"
        },
        {
            "@type": "Person",
            "@id": "#FrancescoClemente"
        }
    ]
}
```

If I were to change the `@type` of `#JeanMichelBasquiat` to lets say `Place`, the [Google Schema Validator](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) would actually complain that for `knows` `Place` is not an expected value. Only `Person` is.
This is great!

Now to the actual problem:

Say I want to make a statement about all `Place`s `#AndyWarhol` has been living for more than a year. So in essence, I'm looking for a one-to-many relation between a `Person` and a `Place`.

As I wasn't able to find it on schema.org, I tried to create it myself and miserably failed.

So my question is:

How do I model structures like `knows` myself?
One thing I could do, is just say that `hasLivedIn` is just a set of `@id`s, but then again there is no way for a parser to validate that the data that has been written is actually valid.

```
{
    "@context": {
        "givenName": "http://schema.org/givenName",
        "hasLivedIn": {
            "@id": "http://schema.org/Place",
            "@type": "@id"
        }
    },
    "@type": "Person",
    "@id": "AndyWarhol",
    "givenName": "Andy",
    "hasLivedIn": [
        "http://newyorkcity.com",
        "http://losangeles.com"
    ]
}
```

(*This doesn't make any sense I guess*)

I also tried using `@container` with `@set` and `@list` to achieve those results:

```
{
    "@context": {
        "givenName": "schema:givenName",
        "hasLivedIn": {
            "@id": "schema:Place",
            "@container": "@set"
        },
        "knows": {
            "@id": "schema:knows",
            "@type": "@id"
        },
        "schema": "http://www.schema.org/"
    },
    "@type": "schema:Person",
    "@id": "AndyWarhol",
    "givenName": "Andy",
    "hasLivedIn": [
        {
            "@type": "schema:Place",
            "@id": "places/nyc"
        },
        {
            "@type": "schema:Place",
            "@id": "places/la"
        }
    ],
    "knows": [
        {
            "@type": "schema:Person",
            "@id": "person/JeanMichelBasquiat"
        },
        {
            "@type": "schema:Person",
            "@id": "person/FrancescoClemente"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here though, when I change one of the respective `@type`s in either `hasLivedIn` or `knows`, the validator is now complaining.

In short:

I want to have a new property called `hasLivedIn`, that takes a list of `Place`s on the level of a `Person`. Ideally, I'm able to define this new property's properties myself.

**Edit**

Here is one I was able to get working:

```
{
    "@context": {
        "@vocab": "http://www.schema.org/",
        "hasLivedIn": "hasPos"
    },
    "@type": "Person",
    "@id": "AndyWarhol",
    "givenName": "Andy",
    "hasLivedIn": [
        {
            "@type": "Place",
            "@id": "places/nyc"
        },
        {
            "@type": "Place",
            "@id": "places/la"
        }
    ]
}
```

I use `hasPOS` and alias it as `hasLivedIn`, which is probably not the right way to do things...